# Relationship between genetic representation and fitness function

Tags: genetic-algorithm, heuristics, evolutionary-algorithm

As you know choosing a genetic representation is a part of building any Genetic Algorithm (GA). A mapping can be hence defined between the genotype space (problem solving space) and the phenotype space (original problem context). The *fitness function*, let's called it *f*, can be this mapping, in case assessing individuals of GA is identical to the objective function of the original problem:

```
f: Genotype Space ---------> Phenotype Space
```

For each genotype there is one corresponding phenotype. So, *f* is injective. A good GA representation encodes all phenotype into genotypes. So, *f*  is bijective. My question: is it  possible to go further and assess the quality of genetic representations by just examining some analytical properties of the fitness function. Thank you.

Comment: *f* is not bijective in real life. The whole of the fitness function is to assess the quality of genetic representations. Why do you want to assess the property of the fitness function?

Comment: I suspect that a hidden relationship exists between properties of fitness function and an efficient representation. If the genotype space changes, the shape of _f_ will be too. But how ? I am still looking for :P

Comment: A fitness function does not map a genotype to a phenotype. It is a mapping from the `genotype space` to the `fitness space`; it simply denotes the suitability of a particular "individual". The [genotype](http://ls11-www.cs.uni-dortmund.de/~beyer/EA-glossary/node61.html#genot) is the coded set of the "individual's" characteristics, i.e., the [phenotype](http://ls11-www.cs.uni-dortmund.de/~beyer/EA-glossary/node107.html#pha).

Comment: So the mapping targets the fitness space which can be different than the phenotype space. That's very good to know. How about the case where the fitness space matches the phenotype space. the fitness function will be a kind of encoding function too .... right?

Comment: @Roney Michael, actually the fitness function maps the phenotype space to the fitness space. You have some genetic code, that is your genotype, that i.e. results in blue eyes and your fitness defines whether blue eyes are good or not. If two identical genotypes would result in the same set of blue eyes the fitness space would not distinguish between them.

Comment: @Omar: The fitness function is a type of encoding, true, but in the general case you need not be able to map the fitness back to the value of x. For example, take the case where the fitness function `F(x)` is defined as a quadratic equation, for a particular value of `F(x)`, multiple values of `x` may exist.

Comment: @Roney Michael and Andreas, I just understand. big Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, as of yet, any set of general guidelines for assessing the quality of a fitness function.

For someone starting out on a genetic algorithm problem, the fitness function is first formulated as a heuristic which suits ones own understanding. Development of "better" measures of fitness are done progressively, with the researcher refining the fitness function as new metrics come to light.

As [the Wikipedia article on fitness functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_function) states:

> Definition of the fitness function is not straightforward in many cases and often is performed iteratively if the fittest solutions produced by GA are not what is desired. In some cases, it is very hard or impossible to come up even with a guess of what fitness function definition might be.

Evaluation of the suitability of fitness function, however, is an active area of research. There has been directed research in the past towards this end, though no promising results have arisen.